# data.table - could not find function "."

Tags: r, data.table

I am working with data.table, and have written a function with a line that looks like this:

```
Qdata <- tbl[.(rep(allSecs, each=length(allDates)),
               rep(allDates, length(allSecs)))]
```

When I try to call this function, I am getting this error:

```
 Error in .(rep(allSecs, each = length(allDates)), rep(allDates, length(allSecs))) : 
  could not find function "."
```

Interestingly, when I run it out line by line in R studio, it works no problem. What could be causing this error?

Comment: should be `tbl[, .(` I think

Comment: @Chris, any idea why it would work when just running that line independently?

Comment: No idea - can you paste the specific lines you are sending to console vs. running together?

Comment: Also when I define the function locally in R studio, it also seems to work fine. Whereas when I call the function that I put into my package, it fails.

Comment: @Chris it sill complains about it even with the tbl[, .(

Comment: Sorry, `[ .() , .() ]` does work for data.tables... second guess would be that tbl is not a data.table but a data.frame instead